# Styling map elements based on their properties

Tags: python, openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik

I am currently generating tiles based on OSM data using Mapnik and Python and am quite happy using the XML styling but I am at a loss as to how to vary the styling on an element by element basis.

I would like to render OSM map tiles where certain elements are styled according to their attributes, for example, a roads colour is based on its length, or an area is coloured based on its size.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Postgis database with osm2pgsql data scheme, you have a column way_area for polygons. Unit is square degrees or google meters, which is only at the aequator eqivalent to real metres:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:way_area

For the length, I guess you have to calculate it on your own. But keep in mind that a road may have been broken up to reflect route relations diverting or joining.

Comment: Thanks, my main issue is with how to change the styling of the rendered item based on way_area or another variable.  Currently I can only define the style that applies to all ways or all areas etc.

Comment: The Style "area-text" has a good example:  <Filter>[way_area] &gt;= 80000 and [way_area] &lt; 150000</Filter>

Comment: Excellent, so if for instance I wanted to vary colour by size in small increments I would have to create a <filter> for each increment? I guess this is the way to do it if there is no way to directly base a colour on variable.  The downside is that the style file could get very large.

Comment: You are right. The size of the style file is no problem: Every rule that does not fit simply gets skipped.